# Do weapons training's bonuses apply to every attack made with a double weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, fighter, magus

> Starting at 5th level, a fighter can select one group of weapons, as noted below. Whenever he attacks with a weapon from this group, he gains a +1 bonus on attack and damage rolls.

Let's say I wanted to use a sword cane pistol, which is a double weapon of a coat pistol and sword cane- the coat pistol being a firearm and the sword cane falling into the "light blade" category for the purposes of weapons training.

If I got weapons training in one of those categories, do I get the +1 bonuses to any attack made with that weapon? IE, let's say I get weapons training in firearms, but attack with the sword cane pistol in melee, or get weapons training in light blades and then fire a bullet from the pistol. I'm more concerned about RAW than flavor.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **neither**, that is, unless your GM decides on adding it to a group (see below). From the PRD (Core Rulebook):

> Weapon groups are defined as follows (GMs may add other weapons to these groups, or add entirely new groups):
>
> Axes: battleaxe, dwarven waraxe, greataxe, handaxe, heavy pick, light
>   pick, orc double axe, and throwing axe.
>
> Blades, Heavy: bastard sword, elven curve blade, falchion, greatsword,
>   longsword, scimitar, scythe, and two-bladed sword.
>
> Blades, Light: dagger, kama, kukri, rapier, sickle, starknife, and
>   short sword.
>
> Bows: composite longbow, composite shortbow, longbow, and shortbow.
>
> Close: gauntlet, heavy shield, light shield, punching dagger, sap,
>   spiked armor, spiked gauntlet, spiked shield, and unarmed strike.
>
> Crossbows: hand crossbow, heavy crossbow, light crossbow, heavy
>   repeating crossbow, and light repeating crossbow.
>
> Double: dire flail, dwarven urgrosh, gnome hooked hammer, orc double
>   axe, quarterstaff, and two-bladed sword.
>
> Flails: dire flail, flail, heavy flail, morningstar, nunchaku, spiked
>   chain, and whip.
>
> Hammers: club, greatclub, heavy mace, light hammer, light mace, and
>   warhammer.
>
> Monk: kama, nunchaku, quarterstaff, sai, shuriken, siangham, and
>   unarmed strike.
>
> Natural: unarmed strike and all natural weapons, such as bite, claw,
>   gore, tail, and wing.
>
> Pole Arms: glaive, guisarme, halberd, and ranseur.
>
> Spears: javelin, lance, longspear, shortspear, spear, and trident.
>
> Thrown: blowgun, bolas, club, dagger, dart, halfling sling staff,
>   javelin, light hammer, net, shortspear, shuriken, sling, spear,
>   starknife, throwing axe, and trident.

In this list there is no entry for the sword cane pistol, which means that the +1 bonus cannot be added.

However, if your GM adds the cane pistol into one of the groups, you **would** get a bonus on all weapon rolls, just as if it was a quarterstaff.

**EDIT:**

However, if you are using the Ultimate Combat rulebook, then you will get the bonus.

Comment: According to page 135 of _Ultimate Combat_, all firearms fall into the "firearm" weapon group. The sword cane pistol is a firearm.

_"All firearms are part of the same weapon group for the
purposes of the fighter’s weapon training class feature."_

Comment: @Max you should contribute that as a correct answer, as it pretty much answers the question...

Comment: +1 for providing lists for reference to the answer, answering the question as given (no references to other books, so I'd assume only the core book was available for RAW), and providing additional info for  circumstances where the sword cane pistol is included in a suitable list. Max's interpretation only cites the swordcane pistol as a firearm, with no mention as to whether a bonus can be applied or not in melee.